# jQuery, trigger a function on press "enter" on jQuery UI autocomplete plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplet exactly like in this example:
http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/html.html

But inside my 'label' keys I have the following HTLML:

```
<span class="whatever">whatever</span>
```

To trigger function on click on class "whatever" I'm using:

```
$(document).on('click', '.whatever', function() {
someFunction();
});
```

Any idea how can I trigger 'someFunction()' when user press 'enter' when focus in on 'whatever' instead of clicking on it?

Comment: you need to bind keyevents for doing that

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code inside your function to get the enter work:-

```
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
}
```

13 is the value for ENTER Key.